# What is wrong with this question ABOUT programing?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/241503/jira-full-blown-solution-for-the-single-developer

what is wrong with this question, in gods name, can someone tell me what the problem is and why it gets blocked right away?

Comment: The discussion was taking a non constructive turn, so I've purged all the comments. Herr K, I don't have a reason to doubt that you've researched your question before posting it. That said, in the future you should try to include at least past of your research in the question, if only to save yourself from answers that just re-iterate the first couple of google results. You can find more details on our expectations on prior research here: [Why is research important?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6559/25936).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The close reason says it all:

> put on hold as primarily opinion-based

There are probably as many views on this topic as there are developers.

Stack Exchange is built around getting *answerable* questions the best possible answer there can be. This means that there has to be a limited number (ideally one, but there are often several ways of skinning any particular cat) of correct answers on which the users can vote so that the "best" one rises to the top.

Your questions doesn't invite that sort of answer. You are actually asking for opinions in the question itself. If you can reformulate the question so that it follows these guidelines then there's a good chance it will be reopened.

Comment: Hello @ChrisF, thank you for your informative answer. I would like to know if the use of JIRA for personal use is good. Is this question in a wrong site here? How could I reformulate that question to line it up with possible "correct" answers?

Comment: @HerrK - You could always pop into chat and ask that question.